# Why is polymer's iron-selector not working for me?

Tags: html, polymer

I am trying to use iron-selector so that I can then dynamically change the main element on my webpage using iron-pages. The code is as follows:

```html
<iron-selector selected='{{choice}}' attr-for-selected='option'>
    <div option='home'>Homepage</a>
    <div option='list'>List</a>
    <div option='delete'>Delete items</a>
</iron-selector>
<h1>Your choice: {{choice}}</h1>
```

Nothing happens, the divs aren't clickable. I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: Have you installed correctly `iron-selector`?

Comment: Yes, and besides, wouldn't I get any errors otherwise?